# A java program to search in a certain website

Tags: java, search

I want to write a Java code to parse a certain website. Each result in the website appear in a specified URL. 
  How can I start? Is there a good library to use? Could I benefit from your experience in this field?

Comment: Sounds like you want to google on java crawler

Comment: yeah I want to google or to bing, by the way I found very useful library called bing sdk on java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for "web crawler" and you'll find many examples (e.g. [Crawler4J](http://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/) or [Crawler](http://java.net/projects/crawler)), how to solve this.

Besides Java, you'll often stumple upon Python when it comes to grepping stuff from web pages - I'm not a Python guy, but it seems to fit for the task.